Django Models - Table and Table status - how to model?
I need some advice...
In my django app, I've got models: Order  and Order status:
class OrderStatus(models.Model): 
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Status")
  
class Order(models.Model): 
    orderNo = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Order", unique=True)
    orderStatus = models.ForeignKey(OrderStatus, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Status"  ) 

There are 3 statuses..: New, In progress, Finished...
In my views, I frequently use a code like: (for example to create Order)
orderx = Order() 
orderStatus1 = OrderStatus.objects.get(pk=1)   # <- the problem is here...
orderx.orderStatus=orderStatus1
orderx.orderNo=i
orderx.save()

The problem, I've got is the one:

I should't get Status object by char content (eg. "New" - because it can change, be in different language etc, so I should't filter it like:
orderStatus1 = OrderStatus.objects.get(status="New")
I also shouldn't get it by id like now:
orderStatus1 = OrderStatus.objects.get(pk=1)
because there is no warranty, that it will be the same ID while placing in other database, etc..

So how should it be modelled, so I can take STATUS_NEW somehow?

Add a marker start_status=models.BooleanField() that is guaranteed to be unique in the OrderStatus?

Sorry, I'm not sure if I understand that answer. My problem is that either taking status by its internal string order value or by its ID , for me smells as a bad practice..

You can add a "flag" is_initial to the OrderStatus that is guaranteed to only be applicable to one record by using a UniqueConstraint [Django-doc]:
from django.db.models import Q


class OrderStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, verbose_name='Status')
    is_initial = models.BooleanField(db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('is_initial',),
                condition=Q(is_initial=True),
                name='one_initial_status',
            )
        ]
then you create an order with:
orderx = Order.objects.create(
    orderStatus=OrderStatus.objects.get(is_initial=True), orderNo=i
)
We can not guarantee that there is at least one such record. In the case we can not find one, we could use NULL/None instead.

Thanks, that is fine. I've also found this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/howto/initial-data/   so that I can populate db at the beginning with my data. Still, I can't see any elegant way to query db for for example "in progress" status,   other then by id=2

@andrew: you can also populate the database with a data migration: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations but you should see primary keys as "blackboxes", and not attach special meaning to these. Even the fact that the pk is an int (or uuid, or something else), is more a technical detail, since adding two primary keys together for example does not make much sense, compared to adding two ints together.
